# delete the selected object from the listView of a MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android

how can I delete object from `ListView` of a `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` when the user clicks on it, and add it back to list when the user deletes the token from the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` how can I do this? I used this custom `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` from https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete

Issue:
when the tokens are added to the textview they are not deleted from the list

Comment: Please mention the part where you find it is not working.

Comment: @jafferwilson when the tokens are added to the textview they are not deleted from the list